# Правильный ли мой код Fragment и почему не работает setRetainInstance(true)?

Tags: java, android, android-fragment, android-dialog

Я начинаю изучение работы с фрагментами. Я хочу попробовать создать тестовый фрагмент, который активити загружает по умолчанию в контейнер. Фрагмент работает с сетью и пользователь в любую минуту может инициировать обновление данных с сервера. Приложение содержит всего несколько фрагментов. Проблемы начинаются, когда нужно обрабатывать события смены ориентации и т.д. Я не хочу использовать что-то на подобии `android:configChanges="orientation|screenSize|keyboardHidden"`, так как Google говорит, что это плохая практика и вообще антипаттерн. Я хочу научиться контролировать приложение через `onSaveInstanceState`. Но даже тогда, когда я устанавливаю фрагменту `setRetainInstance(true)` Android продолжает уничтожать мои `ProgressDialog` или `SwipeRefreshLayout` индикатор (кружочек такой разноцветный) при изменении конфигурации.

Вот мой класс фрагмента и мои решения. Пожалуйста, помогите в его корректировке или укажите на неправильные участки кода.

```
public class HomeFragment extends BaseFragment implements SwipeRefreshLayout.OnRefreshListener {

    private static final String ARG_PARAM1 = "param1";
    private static final String ARG_PARAM2 = "param2";

    private static final String TAG = HomeFragment.class.getSimpleName();

    // TODO: Rename and change types of parameters
    private String mParam1;
    private String mParam2;

    View rootView;

    SwipeRefreshLayout swipeRefreshLayout;

    FragmentOnNetworkRequest onNetworkRequestListener;

    boolean isNetworkingLoading = false;
    boolean isSwipeRefreshShowing = false;
    boolean isProgressDialogShowing = false;

    ProgressDialog dialog;

    public HomeFragment() {
        // Required empty public constructor
    }

    public static HomeFragment newInstance(String param1, String param2) {
        Log.d(TAG, "newInstance");
        HomeFragment fragment = new HomeFragment();
        Bundle args = new Bundle();
        args.putString(ARG_PARAM1, param1);
        args.putString(ARG_PARAM2, param2);
        fragment.setArguments(args);
        return fragment;
    }

    @Override
    public void onAttach(Context context) {
        super.onAttach(context);

        try {
            onNetworkRequestListener = (FragmentOnNetworkRequest) context;
        } catch (ClassCastException e) {
            throw new ClassCastException(context.toString()
                    + " must implement onNetworkRequestListener");
        }
    }

    @Override
    public void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
        super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
        Log.d(TAG, "onCreate");
        setRetainInstance(true);
        if (getArguments() != null) {
            mParam1 = getArguments().getString(ARG_PARAM1);
            mParam2 = getArguments().getString(ARG_PARAM2);
        }
    }

    @Override
    public View onCreateView(LayoutInflater inflater, ViewGroup container,
                             Bundle savedInstanceState) {
        Log.d(TAG, "onCreateView");
        if(rootView != null)
            return rootView;

        rootView = inflater.inflate(R.layout.fragment_home, container, false);

        swipeRefreshLayout = (SwipeRefreshLayout) rootView.findViewById(R.id.fragment_home_swipe_layout);
        swipeRefreshLayout.setColorSchemeColors(
                getResources().getColor(R.color.colorAccent),
                getResources().getColor(R.color.colorPrimary));
        swipeRefreshLayout.setOnRefreshListener(this);

        Random r = new Random();
        int rand = r.nextInt(100 - 1) + 1;
        TextView textView = (TextView) rootView.findViewById(R.id.textViewHome);
        textView.setText("HOME FRAGMENT "+rand);

        return rootView;
    }

    @Override
    public void onViewCreated(View view, @Nullable Bundle savedInstanceState) {
        super.onViewCreated(view, savedInstanceState);

        Log.d(TAG, "onViewCreated");

        // Fragment was created in first time
        if(savedInstanceState == null) {
            showLoadingDialog();
            initDataFromServer();
        }
        else {
            // continue show loading anim
            isNetworkingLoading = savedInstanceState.getBoolean("isNetworkingLoading");
            isProgressDialogShowing = savedInstanceState.getBoolean("isProgressDialogShowing");
            isSwipeRefreshShowing = savedInstanceState.getBoolean("isSwipeRefreshShowing");
            updateViews();
        }
    }

    @Override
    public void onSaveInstanceState(Bundle outState) {
        super.onSaveInstanceState(outState);
        Log.d(TAG, "onSaveInstanceState");
        outState.putBoolean("isNetworkingLoading", isNetworkingLoading);
        outState.putBoolean("isProgressDialogShowing", isProgressDialogShowing);
        outState.putBoolean("isSwipeRefreshShowing", isSwipeRefreshShowing);
    }

    @Override
    public void onPause() {
        super.onPause();
        forceHideSwipeRefresh();
        forceHideLoadingDialog();
    }

    public void updateViews()
    {
        Log.d(TAG, "updateViews(): isNetworkingLoading = "+isNetworkingLoading);
        Log.d(TAG, "updateViews(): isSwipeRefreshShowing = "+isSwipeRefreshShowing);
        Log.d(TAG, "updateViews(): isProgressDialogShowing = "+isProgressDialogShowing);

        if(isNetworkingLoading && isSwipeRefreshShowing)
            showSwipeRefresh();

        if(isNetworkingLoading && isProgressDialogShowing)
            showLoadingDialog();
    }

    public void showSwipeRefresh() {
        isSwipeRefreshShowing = true;
        swipeRefreshLayout.post(new Runnable() {
            @Override
            public void run() {
                swipeRefreshLayout.setRefreshing(true);
            }
        });
    }

    public void hideSwipeRefresh() {
        isSwipeRefreshShowing = false;
        if (swipeRefreshLayout.isRefreshing()) {
            swipeRefreshLayout.setRefreshing(false);
        }
    }

    public void forceHideSwipeRefresh() {
        if (swipeRefreshLayout != null) {
            swipeRefreshLayout.setRefreshing(false);
            swipeRefreshLayout.destroyDrawingCache();
            swipeRefreshLayout.clearAnimation();
        }
    }

    private void initDataFromServer()
    {
        isNetworkingLoading = true;
        onNetworkRequestListener.onNetworkRequest(this);
    }

    public void showLoadingDialog()
    {
        isProgressDialogShowing = true;
        dialog = new ProgressDialog(getContext());
        dialog.setProgressStyle(ProgressDialog.STYLE_SPINNER);
        dialog.setMessage("Loading. Please wait...");
        dialog.setCancelable(false);
        dialog.setCanceledOnTouchOutside(false);
        dialog.show();
    }

    public void hideLoadingDialog()
    {
        isProgressDialogShowing = false;
        forceHideLoadingDialog();
    }

    public void forceHideLoadingDialog()
    {
        if(dialog != null) {
            dialog.dismiss();
            dialog = null;
        }
    }

    @Override
    public void onNetworkResponse(String response) {
        Log.d(TAG, "onNetworkResponse(): response = "+response);
        isNetworkingLoading = false;
        hideSwipeRefresh();
        hideLoadingDialog();
    }

    @Override
    public void onRefresh() {
        isSwipeRefreshShowing = true;
        initDataFromServer();
    }
}
```

Фрагмент в принципе работает нормально, но я чувствую что-то здесь не так и не совсем правильно. Уж очень много флагов только для проверки аля показывался ли какой-то крутящийся кружочек и т.д.

Answer (score 1):

Retain-фрагменты, так же как и *обычные* фрагменты, после изменения конфигурации устройства отрисовываются заново. Ключевое отличие retain-фрагментов от *обычных* заключается в том, что retain-фрагменты сохраняют свое состояние (состояние полей класса).

Если Вы используете retain-фрагменты, то нет смысла сохранять что-либо с помощью `onSaveInstanceState(...)` и потом восстанавливать – состояние объектов будет сохранено и восстановлено автоматически.

Retain-фрагменты следует использовать в том случае, когда во фрагменте хранятся объекты, состояние которых сохранить нельзя (например, объекты классов для работы с интернетом, для воспроизведения аудио).

Comment: Да, действительно, закомментировал эти строки `//isNetworkingLoading = savedInstanceState.getBoolean("isNetworkingLoading");//outState.putBoolean("isNetworkingLoading", isNetworkingLoading);` фрагмент работает правильно. Теперь стало понятней, как работает `setRetainInstance()`. Я так понимаю, это справедливо только для тех фрагментов, которые не находятся в backStack? Как быть с остальными фрагментами? Не подскажите, как код в остальном? Потому что я собираюсь использовать его в дальнейшем во всех своих приложениях. И правильно ли то, что я вручную восстанавливаю индикаторы и progressDialog?

Comment: `это справедливо только для тех фрагментов, которые не находятся в backStack'е` – с чего Вы это взяли? По поводу кода – я не вижу необходимости использования `setRetainInstance(true);` в Вашем фрагменте.

Comment: `с чего Вы это взяли?`  https://developer.android.com/reference/android/app/Fragment.html#setRetainInstance(boolean)

Comment: @Trancer, Тогда да, только для фрагментов, которые не находятся в бэк-стеке.

Comment: Все-таки никак не получается при возвращении на фрагмент по кнопке назад проверить, нужно ли подгрузить данные с сервера и обновить `Views` или нет. Смысл следующий: при первом открытии фрагмента загрузить данные из интернета и применить к `Views`, если фрагмент открыт по кнопке Назад, то показать фрагмент со старыми данными, a пользователь по своему желанию может обновить данные, потянув `SwipeRefreshLayout` вниз

Comment: Я думаю, я нашел решение. Нужно ввести еще одно булевое поле isFragmentAlreadyLoaded и в `onViewCreated` изменить код и добавить проверку `if(savedInstanceState == null && !isFragmentAlreadyLoaded)`.